# Don't prepend WordPress base url to image paths

Tags: themes, filters, hooks

I'm programmatically adding image attachments to posts, however I'm not uploading the image, just storing the full url which is hosted on a CDN e.g.

`https://i.atcdn.co.uk/imgser-uk/imgser-uk/servlet/media.jpg?id=fa348829bc924e28a649624e52f7191e&width=1024&height=768`

However when the template is rendered it prepends the base url e.g.

`http://localhost:8888/wordpress/https://i.atcdn.co.uk/imgser-uk/imgser-uk/servlet/media.jpg?id=fa348829bc924e28a649624e52f7191e&width=1024&height=768`

I'm trying to hook into the media attachments to sort this out but I can't get anything to work.

Are there any filter hooks available so I can not prepend the base url if the path starts with r'http[s]?://' ?

**Edit**

This is the code I'm using to add the images:

```
$file = 'https://i.atcdn.co.uk/imgser-uk/imgser-uk/servlet/media.jpg?id=fa348829bc924e28a649624e52f7191e&width=1024&height=768';

$attachment = array(
    'post_title' => $file,
    'post_mime_type' => "image/jpg",
);

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file);
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $file);
wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
```

Comment: How are you adding these URLs to begin with?

Comment: I've just edited the post

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert remote file in this manner.

```
<?php wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $parent_post_id ); ?>
```

> $filename (string) (optional) Location of the file on the server. Use
>   **absolute path and not the URI of the file**. The file MUST be in the
>   uploads

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment

You should first download it to temp dir.

If you wish to keep files on your CDN and simply save URI, consider adding a custom field and saving it there.

Comment: How do you associate media files that don't live on the server with a post?

Comment: @dpdenton Use post_meta (custom fields) to store remote files. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta